# Json payload to string without spaces and newline characters

Tags: c#, .net, azure-eventhub

I'm consuming events from Azure Event Hub, and need to log the event payload as a string. The payload is in JSON format.

```
private readonly EventProcessorClient _eventProcessor;
_eventProcessor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessMessage;
```

I've tried this:

```
private async Task ProcessMessage(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   string stringPayload1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.Span);
   Console.WriteLine(stringPayload1);
   string stringPayload2 = eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToString();  // EventBody is BinaryData
   Console.WriteLine(stringPayload2);
}
```

but in both cases they contain spaces. output:

```
 {    "data": [        {            "name": "cpuUsage",            "value": "18"        },        {            "name": "cpuTemperature",            "value": "49"        },        {            "name": "memoryUsage",            "value": "24"        },        {            "name": "storageUsage",            "value": "23"        },        {            "name": "storageHealth",            "value": "90"        }    ],    "datacontenttype": "application/json",    "id": "cd31d925-b600-4d5b-89eb-25c30388ecce",    "source": "/CCZ15A60022248000012",    "specversion": "1.0",    "time": "2023-08-15T12:21:08",    "type": "telemetry"}
```

I need this compact output

```
{"data":[{"name":"cpuUsage","value":"18"},{"name":"cpuTemperature","value":"49"},{"name":"memoryUsage","value":"24"},{"name":"storageUsage","value":"23"},{"name":"storageHealth","value":"90"}],"datacontenttype":"application/json","id":"cd31d925-b600-4d5b-89eb-25c30388ecce","source":"/CCZ15A60022248000012","specversion":"1.0","time":"2023-08-15T12:21:08","type":"telemetry"}
```

There is no possibility to ask the producers they remove all spaces before sending.
Are there any ways to achieve that without `string.Replace`?

Why the EventHub does not compress the JSON payload? It is inefficient because my message contains useless symbols that affect the message size

Comment: Parse the JSON, write as JSON again without indentation.

Comment: @CodeCaster I cannot parse to some specific object because the payload can be different. I need to log it before deserialization

Comment: Then parse it, but not to some specific object.

Comment: can I do it with BinaryData class? could you pls point me. Isn't it redundant work?

Comment: this way? `object objectPayload = eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToObjectFromJson();
string stringPayload = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(objectPayload).ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deserialize it and serialize it back. For example with `System.Text.Json` (which by default writes data without extra whitespace, see [`JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.writeindented?view=net-7.0)) you can use `JsonDocument` as "intermediate" type:

```
// or JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(stringPayload1)
using var jdoc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(eventArgs.Data.Body.Span); 

var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jdoc);
```

Comment: thx. wouldn't be more efficient to use string.Replace or Regex?

Comment: @Darkside NO, please don't do that. Regex are not suitable for parsing or modifying JSON. What if some of the data contains a space. Like `{"foo":"bar baz"}`  Writing a regex that doesn't replace the space within the value is (even possible) very complicated ...

Comment: @Darkside you will need to test, but I would argue that using `string.Replace` would be much more cumbersome - consider "nested" whitespace in some string properties.